# retrieving only the required tag from http request into node js console application

Tags: node.js, string-matching

I am retrieving a certain amount data into a node js console application and the results is as shown in the image. My question here is, I dont want all the tags to be displayed in the console. I just want the 'revenuegrowth' tag to be displayed. I have tried a few things related to js regex but i am not able to find a solution for this one. I feel this is quite simple but i am not able to do it. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSxtq.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: I got it. It was damn simple. Being really new i am getting to learn a lot of things. I tried to access it by coding it as "data.results[0]" which was wrong! The correct way to do it was "data[0]" to get to display only the 'revenuegrowth' tag. Thanks for your response.